# Block views cause page.tpl.php not to render

Tags: views, theming

Weird problem -- not sure what is going on. I have a view, which is stored as a block, and that block is shown in the "Content" region of a custom theme which is itself a sub-theme.

The sub-theme implements block.tpl, region.tpl, etc but very minimally:

```
<?php print $content; ?>
```

The base theme page.tpl however is static text and requires overloading in any sub-theme -- which I have done quite simply by copying the single line above.

This works on all pages except when I am viewing the View -- in which case if I add any markup to the page.tpl.php the result is blank whiteness :s

The page in question is programmatically generated via hook_menu and a callback which in return invokes the view and passing arguments.

Any ideas???

Comment: What version of Drupal are you using? Rendering content in Drupal 7's page.tpl.php is <?php print render($page['content']); ?>

Comment: I believe that was it...silly me...to create the page.tpl.php I copied the block.tpl.php from the sub-theme...thank you :)